# Apple II double buffering and double high resolution

Tags: apple-ii

I write programs in assembly language using HGR mode.
For a fluid display, I use the double buffering technique.
Is it possible to use this technique in DHGR (double high resolution)?
If so, I am looking for examples or explanations to do so.

Comment: It's possible, and Raffzahn's answer explains the options. Some old programming books will cover DHR, but probably not page flipping. As for examples, there aren't many tutorials these days on DHR! There's [this series](http://www.battlestations.zone/2017/04/apple-ii-double-hi-res-from-ground-up.html), but it probably doesn't do exactly what you want. You can inspect old games and verify whether they use DHR and page flipping. For instance, [Airheart](https://archive.org/details/a2_Airheart_1986_Broderbund_cr_Evil_Sock) does.

Answer (score 4):

*[The following is written under the assumption it's done in Assembly. For BASIC it works rather different, but doable]*

> I write programs in assembly language using HGR mode. For a fluid display, I use the double buffering technique.

I assume by alternate use of Page 1 ($2000) and Page 2 ($4000), right?

> Is it possible to use this technique in DHGR (double high resolution)?

Yes, works exactly like in normal High-Res. Except of course now Page 1X and 2X in Aux-RAM have to be handled as well.

> If so, I am looking for examples or explanations to do so.

It's *reading* the usual switches:

- $C056/57 switch on/off High-Res
- $C054/55 switch to Page 2 / back to Page 1
- $C05E    (AN3) turn on Double Highres

If you want to use mixed text mode as well, then

- $C053    *reading* turns it on mixed mode, while
- $C00D    *writing* enables 80 column text.

Writing to either page is as well simple for *basic* usage.

- $C004/05 (RAMWRT) redirects writes to either 'side' of Aux-RAM

This is done for the whole area from $0200 to $BFFF, so essentially the entire basic RAM except for zero page and stack. So a safe write routine will load a byte, switch on Aux-RAM, write it and swich back. Something like:

```
       LDA  some_byte    ; Whatever data we want to move
       STA  $C005        ; Switch writing to Aux-RAM
       STA  target_loc
       STA  $C004        ; And switching write back to main memory.
```

Of course one may copy more bytes at once, reading them from main and writing to Aux-RAM. The fine part of zero page not being switched allows to keep pointers there, regardless of how RAMWRT is set.

Now, reading from Aux gets a bit more complex, as simply setting RAMRD ($C002/03) would as well start to read code from Aux-RAM, so code must reside in ZP, stack or Language Card RAM. Well, or keeping a copy in Aux-RAM at the same address, which would make it resistent any flip between main and Aux-RAM. Doesn't need to be the whole program, just the routines that do switch reading.

At this point I would **recomend to read Apple's own [Apple IIe Technical Note #3](https://apple2.org.za/gswv/USA2WUG/IIe.Dev.TechNotes/APPLE2E3.TXT)** which describes all switching and relation between these switches in great deail.

Comment: Is double buffering on the Apple II fast enough for a "fluid display"?

Comment: @snips-n-snails Define 'Fluid Display'. The Apple got two screen pages. [Flipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Page_flipping) between them is instant (well, one 4 microsecond long instruction it is), thus for sure fast enough to flip 60 times per second. If 16 ms are enough to draw a new screen with a 1 MHz 6502 is a different issue and may rather depends on the game.

Comment: @snips-n-snails: Have a look at [Airheart](https://archive.org/details/a2_Airheart_1986_Broderbund_cr_Evil_Sock) and see for yourself. ; - )

Comment: D/Generation (in [this collection](https://archive.org/details/TotalReplay)) is perhaps a better example, given that it is much more visually complex, but yes it is indeed fast enough.

Comment: I made several animations using double buffering, it works rather, for a machine dating back 40 years. Watch this: https://github.com/bruno185/Apple-II-Wolf-animation-as-tribute. They are in He Res, not Double Hi Res.But I had to put significant time delay between each frame. Which assumes that I still have enough time to use the DHGR, which requires twice as much byte manipulation.

Comment: @bruno185 Cool, except to 'watch' the demo a (youtube) Video might be more appropriate than the source, wouldn't it?